# Matplotlib - stop/limit x axis to 100% (instead of bleeding over into 105) when using MultipleLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

The following code :

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(1000)),
        "y": np.random.randint(0, 4, size=1000),
    }
)
pd.crosstab(df["x"], df["y"], normalize="columns").mul(100).T.plot.barh(
    stacked=True, ax=ax
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=5))
```

Will output:

[image]

If the line

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=5))
```

Is removed, the limit is as expected (100) :

[image]

How can `MultipleLocator` be used in this case, without pushing the axis over the limit of 100 ?

---

Comment: If you want to limit the x-axis while leaving the locator in place, I think you can add the following. `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=5));ax.set_xlim(0,100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As r-beginners already pointed out in the comment, you can use [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) in order to set x axis limits:

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
```

[image]